# How can I make a JSON Object containing two properties from a JSON Object containing four properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
[
    {'car':'punto','brand':'fiat','color':'black','model':'2007'},

    {'car':'XUV500','brand':'Mahindra','color':'black','model':'2008'},

    {'car':'Eartiga','brand':'Maruti','color':'black','model':'2009'}
]
```

I want to achieve this:

```
[
   {'car':'punto','brand':'fiat'},

   {'car':'XUV500','brand':'Mahindra'},

   {'car':'Eartiga','brand':'Maruti'}
]
```

How can I achieve it using javascript and Jquery. Any help isappreciated!

Comment: Just a note, that there is not such a thing as `JSON Object`, it's either a `JavaScript Object` or a `JSON string`.

Comment: that is a JSON conform string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE 2022

You could just map the wanted properties by destructuring and short hand properties.

```js
const
    data = [{ car: 'punto', brand: 'fiat', color: 'black', model: '2007' }, { car: 'XUV500', brand: 'Mahindra', color: 'black', model: '2008' }, { car: 'Eartiga', brand: 'Maruti', color: 'black', model: '2009' }],
    result= data.map(({ car, brand }) => ({ car, brand }));

console.log(result);
```

Depending on the need, you have basically two possibillities to tackle the problem:

- rebuild the array with new objects, keeps the original array;
- delete unwanted properties from each object, which modifies the original array.

```js
var data = [{ 'car': 'punto', 'brand': 'fiat', 'color': 'black', 'model': '2007' }, { 'car': 'XUV500', 'brand': 'Mahindra', 'color': 'black', 'model': '2008' }, { 'car': 'Eartiga', 'brand': 'Maruti', 'color': 'black', 'model': '2009' }],
    data1 = data.map(function (a) {
        return { car: a.car, brand: a.brand };
    });

data.forEach(function (a) {
    delete a.color;
    delete a.model;
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use map function in javascript

try this

```js
x = [{
  'car': 'punto',
  'brand': 'fiat',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2007'
}, {
  'car': 'XUV500',
  'brand': 'Mahindra',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2008'
}, {
  'car': 'Eartiga',
  'brand': 'Maruti',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2009'
}]

var result = x.map(function(v) {
  return {
    car: v.car,
    brand: v.brand
  }
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each item in the array and create a new array with the data you want.

```
var originalArray = [{
  'car': 'punto',
  'brand': 'fiat',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2007'
}, {
  'car': 'XUV500',
  'brand': 'Mahindra',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2008'
}, {
  'car': 'Eartiga',
  'brand': 'Maruti',
  'color': 'black',
  'model': '2009'
}];

var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
  var originalItem = originalArray[i];
  newItem = {
    car: originalItem.car,
    brand: originalItem.brand
  };
  newArray.push(newItem);
}
console.debug(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oldJson = [
  {'car':'punto','brand':'fiat','color':'black','model':'2007'},
  {'car':'XUV500','brand':'Mahindra','color':'black','model':'2008'},
  {'car':'Eartiga','brand':'Maruti','color':'black','model':'2009'}
];
var newJson = [];

for(var key in oldJson) {
  newJson.push({
    'car' : oldJson[key].car,
    'brand' : oldJson[key].brand
  })
}
console.log(newJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
function getIwanttoList() {
    var data = [
        {
            'text': '----- Select what you want -----',
            'value': '',
        }, {
            'text': 'Ask a question',
            'value': 'AskAQuestion',
        }, {
            'text': 'Report a content issue',
            'value': 'ReportContentIssue',
        }, {
            'text': 'Propose an idea or quality improvement',
            'value': 'ProposeImprovements',
        }, {
            'text': 'Submit content for governance',
            'value': 'SubmitContent',
        }
    ];
    return data;
}
```